# Unable to compile Google Cloud app code to java 1.7 - Version is always 1.8

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

I have recently started using Google Cloud App Engine for developing some test apps.
As stated in official docs, the standard environment only supports Java 7.
I am using:

- Mac OS for dev where i had previously installed Java-8.
- Eclipse Neon 2 for java ee developers (Also tried Eclipse Mars 2)
- Tomcat 8.0.  (I previously had 8.5 installed).

My problem is that even when changing the compiler level to 1.7 i am still getting this error:
Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: org/eclipse/jetty/apache/jsp/JuliLog.class in /Users/eliokhattar/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.50/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.50/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.16.v20170120-nolog.jar
```

I have tried all the below with no success:

- a) Installed JDK 7 & Removed JDK 8
- b) Updated JAVA HOME to 1.7  (export JAVA_HOME=.....)
- c) Made sure my pom.xml is using java 7
- d) Made sure from project fact java version is 1.7
- e) Ran mvn -version and the java version is 1.7

Note: My target runtime used to be apache 8.5 , but i changed it back to apache 8.0  (can this be related somehow?)

Below is screenshot of [java version from project facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2wYI.png) and its similar from the java build path.

Appreciate ur help resolving (or help me better debug it) the issue as it has taken me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the facet configuration you have Servlet 3.1 support (Dynamic Web facet version 3.1). Google App Engine Standard currently only supports Servlet 2.5 specification. The error message is confusing though.

Please check out this [issue on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/1365) you may experience the same thing.